# How to validate numeric input in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'd like to know how to limit an input value to signed decimals using `std::cin`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
double i;

//Reading the value
cin >> i;

//Numeric input validation
if(!cin.eof())
{
    peeked = cin.peek();
    if(peeked == 10 && cin.good())
    {
             //Good!
             count << "i is a decimal";
        }
        else
        {
             count << "i is not a decimal";
         cin.clear();
         cin >> discard;
        }
}
```

This also gives an error message with the input -1a2.0 avoiding the assignation of just -1 to i.

Comment: #1: What is `discard`? #2: Why `10`? What about Mac? #3: How do you form a loop for retrying? When you wrote it try the input `"ddd"`. You will get your errors many times. If not, then I'm really curious about your solution.

Comment: Is that supposed to be `int peeked`?  https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/peek says it returns a character or `Traits:eof()`.

Answer (score 5):

If the backing variable of the `cin` is a number, and the string provided is not a number, the return value is false, so you need a loop:

```
int someVal;

while(!(cin >> someVal)) {
   cin.reset();
   cout << "Invalid value, try again.";
}
```

Comment: play.cpp:10: error: 'struct std::istream' has no member named 'reset'

Comment: And also - if I replace the reset() with clear(), which you meant or not - it leads to infinite loop when a non-numeric input is given.

Answer (score 2):

Combining the techniques from the top answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c) and [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/135-stream-states-and-input-validation/) website, I get

input.h

```
#include <ios>  // Provides ios_base::failure
#include <iostream>  // Provides cin

template <typename T>
T getValidatedInput()
{
    // Get input of type T
    T result;
    cin >> result;

    // Check if the failbit has been set, meaning the beginning of the input
    // was not type T. Also make sure the result is the only thing in the input
    // stream, otherwise things like 2b would be a valid int.
    if (cin.fail() || cin.get() != '\n')
    {
        // Set the error state flag back to goodbit. If you need to get the input
        // again (e.g. this is in a while loop), this is essential. Otherwise, the
        // failbit will stay set.
        cin.clear();

        // Clear the input stream using and empty while loop.
        while (cin.get() != '\n')
            ;

        // Throw an exception. Allows the caller to handle it any way you see fit
        // (exit, ask for input again, etc.)
        throw ios_base::failure("Invalid input.");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage

inputtest.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>  // Provides EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <iostream>  // Provides cout, cerr, endl

#include "input.h"  // Provides getValidatedInput<T>()

int main()
{
    using namespace std;

    int input;

    while (true)
    {
        cout << "Enter an integer: ";

        try
        {
            input = getValidatedInput<int>();
        }
        catch (exception e)
        {
            cerr << e.what() << endl;
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    cout << "You entered: " << input << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Sample run

Enter an integer: **a**
Invalid input.
Enter an integer: **2b**
Invalid input.
Enter an integer: **3**
You entered: 3.

Answer (score 1):

cin's >> operator works by reading one character at a time until it hits whitespace.  That will slurp the whole string `-1a2.0`, which is obviously not a number so the operation fails.  It looks like you actually have three fields there, -1, a, and 2.0.  If you separate the data by whitespace, cin will be able to read each one without problem.  Just remember to read a `char` for the second field.

Answer (score 1):

I tried many techniques for reading integer input from the user using the `>>` operator, but in a way or another all my experiments have failed.

Now I think that `getline()` function (not the method with the same name on `std::istream`) and the `strtol()` function from the include `cstdlib` is the only predictable consistent solution for this problem. I would appreciate if someone proved me wrong. Here is something like the one I use:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

// @arg prompt The question to ask. Will be used again on failure.
int GetInt(const char* prompt = "? ")
{
    using namespace std; // *1
    while(true)
    {
        cout << prompt;
        string s;
        getline(cin,s);
        char *endp = 0;
        int ret = strtol(s.c_str(),&endp,10);
        if(endp!=s.c_str() && !*endp)
            return ret;
    }
}
```

- *1: Placing `using namespace whatever;` to the global scope may lead to broken "unity builds" (google!) on larger projects, so should be avoided. Practice to not use that way, even on smaller projects!
- Reading integers from files is a very different matter. Raúl Roa's approach can be good for that if properly worked out. I also suggest that wrong input files should not be tolerated, but it really depends on the application.
- Be warned that using `>>` and `getline()` in the same program on `cin` will lead to some problems. Use one of them only, or google to know how to handle the issue (not too hard).

Answer (score -5):

Something like:

```
double a;
cin >> a;
```

Should read your signed "decimal" fine.

You'll need a loop and some code to make sure it handles invalid input in a sensible way.

Good luck!