# how do I check if input from cin is a double?

Tags: c++, validation, double, cin

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to validate numeric input C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c)
>   [how do I validate user input as a double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c)

I need to get input from the command line and check if it is a valid number... storing it as a double. If the input is invalid, I need to keep asking for a number.

```
double x;
cout << '>';
cin >> x;


while (/*x is invalid*/){
 cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a number." << endl;
 cout << '>';
 cin >> x;
}
```

So how do I check if it is valid?

Comment: possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c

Answer (score 2):

parse the string and check if there are numbers and 0 or one dot.
If these rules aren't met, you just print an error message.

Comment: how do I do this... I've never programmed before.

Comment: oh in this case, just look here on stackoverflow for "C++ Tutorial" for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909323/what-are-good-online-resources-or-tutorials-to-learn-c      or use google or something.

Answer (score 2):

See "[How to validate numeric input in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c)" - already asked and answered on the site.