# how do I validate user input as a double in C++?

Tags: c++, validation, double, cin

How would I check if the input is really a double?

```
double x;

while (1) {
    cout << '>';
    if (cin >> x) {
        // valid number
        break;
    } else {
        // not a valid number
        cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
    }
}
//do other stuff...
```

The above code infinitely outputs the `Invalid Input!` statement, so its not prompting for another input. I want to prompt for the input, check if it is legitimate... if its a double, go on... if it is NOT a double, prompt again.

Any ideas?

Comment: Be sure to look at the formatting guide next time you make a post.  Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean? what is wrong with the formatting?

Comment: I edited your post, but before the edit the code wasn't formatted.  Click "edited N mins ago" to see the original post.

Comment: I see... I thought I had done that... must have missed the formatting button and pressed something else by accident. My apologies.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this:

```
while (1) {
  if (cin >> x) {
      // valid number
      break;
  } else {
      // not a valid number
      cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
      cin.clear();
      while (cin.get() != '\n') ; // empty loop
  }
}
```

This basically clears the error state, then reads and discards everything that was entered on the previous line.

Comment: is this inside the `while(1)` loop?

Comment: Yes, inside your existing loop. I've just reproduced the inner part.

Comment: Ok that works. Can you explain the logic behind the empty loop? What exactly is going on in there? What does `get()` do?

Comment: Since `cin >> x` expects a number, you need to clear any invalid input that was previously entered. `get()` simply reads one character at a time, and the loop continues until it reaches the end of the line.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense... seems inefficient but since I'm dealing with a small number of characters, reading to the end of the line won't be difficult. I know there is a difference between Windows and UNIX in ending a line... something like `\r` in Windows? Will your solution work in both environments?

Comment: Instead of `while(cin.get() != '\n');`, I'd just use `cin.sync();`.  It's more readable in my opinion.

Comment: In UNIX, it's a `\r\n`, so there's still a `\n` at the end. So yes, it will work.

Comment: @Hristo: From http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/sync/ It "synchronizes the buffer associated with the stream to its controlled input sequence. This effectively means that the unread characters in the buffer are discarded."

Comment: @chaosTechnician: +1. I had no idea there was a ready-made method to do this. @Hristo: I just searched for `sync` and here's a [reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/istream/sync/). I guess you could replace the `while` loop with a single call to `sync` then.

Comment: @chaosTechnician, cin.sync() doesn't work for me when I try this example. the while(cin.get() != '\n'); does though. Any idea why?

Comment: @Mahmoud: When you say it doesn't work, what is it doing?  The above code (with `sync()` used instead of the loop) works fine for me using VS2008's compiler and GCC.  Are you replacing more than just the loop with `sync()` or using a non-standard compiler?

Comment: I'm using g++ (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3. I copy and pasted the Hristo's code and tried it and it still giving me an infinite loop of 'Invalid Input! Please..."

Comment: No, it's written before: cin.sync(); Here's a snippet of the code:


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  double x;

  while (1) {
    cout << '>';
    if (cin >> x)
    {
      break;
    }
    else
    {
      // not a valid number
      cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
      cin.clear();
      cin.sync();
      // while(cin.get() != '\n');
    }
  }
  cout << "you entered: " << x << endl;
  return 0;
}

Comment: Maybe it is a bug in the GNU version? I really hate cin. For many years now. `getline()` function (sic) for the win. Nothing else worked for me yet.

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelkader cin.sync() is pain by design: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=46624 . The newline is different on various platforms and we may want to stop at spaces too, so `cin.ignore()` is also hard. I decided to solve this issue of flushing a bit of input buffer by reading a word into a dummy `std::string`. Relatively simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

I would use:

```
double x;

while (!(std::cin >> x)) {
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(2147483647, '\n');
  std::cout << "Error.\n";
}
```

or

```
double x;

while ((std::cout << "> ") && !(std::cin >> x)) {
  std::cin.clear();
  std::cin.ignore(2147483647, '\n');
  std::cout << "Error.\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`failbit` will be set after using an extraction operator if there was a parse error, there are a couple simple test functions `good` and `fail` you can check.  They are exactly the opposite of each other because they handle `eofbit` differently, but that's not an issue in this example.

Then, you have to clear `failbit` before trying again.

As casablanca says, you also have to discard the non-numeric data still left in the input buffer.

So:

```
double x;

while (1) {
    cout << '>';
    cin >> x;
    if (cin.good())
        // valid number
        break;
    } else {
        // not a valid number
        cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(100000, '\n');
    }
}
//do other stuff...
```

Comment: this is still causing the infinite loop to print the `Invalid Input!`... its not prompting for another input.

Comment: What does the `cin.ignore()` do?

Comment: Same thing as casablanca's loop, it throws away all characters up to and including the newline to get rid of whatever non-numeric data caused the first extraction to fail.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

bool askForDouble(char const *question, double &ret)
{
        using namespace std;
        while(true)
        {
                cout << question << flush;
                cin >> ret;
                if(cin.good())
                {
                        return true;
                }
                if(cin.eof())
                {
                        return false;
                }
                // (cin.fail() || cin.bad()) is true here
                cin.clear();  // clear state flags
                string dummy;
                cin >> dummy; // discard a word
        }
}

int main()
{
        double x;
        if(askForDouble("Give me a floating point number! ",x))
        {
                std::cout << "The double of it is: " << (x*2) << std::endl;
        } else
        {
                std::cerr << "END OF INPUT" << std::endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Input validation should have been an easier task to do. It makes it very hard to teach newbies and help them enjoy what they are doing. I would like to see a bulletproof and still useful tutorial on cin and cout for newbies.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool is_double(double val)
{
bool answer;
double chk;
int double_equl = 0;     
double strdouble = 0.0;
strdouble = val;           
double_equl = (int)val;
chk = double_equl / strdouble;
if (chk == 1.00)
{
 answer = false; // val is integer
 return answer;
} else {
answer = true;  // val is double
return answer;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One way is to check for floating number equality.

```
double x;

while (1) {
    cout << '>';
    cin >> x;
    if (x != int(x)) {
        // valid number
        break;
    } else {
        // not a valid number
        cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: how does this check for type `double`?

Comment: This just checks if the input had a fractional part, which is probably not what was meant by the question.

Comment: Yeah, most of us know what Hristo meant but this answer does address the question he asked: "How would I check if the input is really a double?"  Interpreting that as, "I assume I'm getting numbers, how do I ensure they aren't whole numbers?" makes this a perfectly useful answer.  No need to downvote, imo.

Comment: @chaosTechnician The error message says "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value.". Whole and not-whole numbers are both "numerical values". So this answer's intention is very unclear for me. Not down-voting anyway. :-)