# c++, how to verify if the data input is of the correct datatype

Tags: c++, cin

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [how do I validate user input as a double in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c)

I am new to C++, and I have a function in which I am wanting the user to input a `double` value. How would I go about insuring that the value input was of the correct datatype? Also, how would an error be handled? At the moment this is all I have:

```
if(cin >> radius){}else{}
```

I using `try{}catch(){}, but I don't think that would the right solution for this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This works pretty well: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/istream-and-ignore.html

Comment: read as string and parse using regex.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If `ostream& operator>>(ostream& , T&)` fails the extraction of formatted data (such as integer, double, float, ...), `stream.fail()` will be true and thus `!stream` will evaluate to true too.

So you can use

```
cin >> radius;
if(!cin){
    cout << "Bad value!";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
    cin >> radius;
}
```

or simply

```
while(!(cin >> radius)){
    cout << "Bad value!";
    cin.clear();
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
}
```

It is important to `ignore` the rest of the line, since `operator>>` won't extract any data from the stream anymore as it is in a wrong format. So if you remove

```
cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

your loop will never end, as the input isn't cleared from the standard input.

See also:

- [`std::basic_istream::ignore`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) (`cin.ignore`)
- [`std::basic_istream::fail`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/good)   (`cin.fail()`)
- [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) (used for the maximum number of ignored characters, defined in `<limits>`).

Comment: `sream.good()` may be false even if the input is correct.  And when using the stream in a boolean context, false is `stream.fail()`, and true is `!stream.fail()`; `stream.good()` never enters into it.  Any reference to `istream::good` with regards to the poster's problem is wrong.

Comment: Your statement that `operator>>` won't extract any data from the stream if it's not in the correct format is also wrong; it may extract _some_ of the data.  (Think of an input along the lines of `"1.2e+x"`.  Streams only guarantee one character look-ahead, and the error cannot be detected until the the `'x'` is seen.  All previous characters will be extracted.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: I tried to take care of the concerns in both of your comments, however, it still feels a little bit clumsy. I'll have a look later, if you find any other mistake feel free to edit and leave a comment. It's always good to learn something new :).

Answer (score 3):

You need to read the entire line using `std::getline` and `std::string`. That is the way to fully verify that the entire line is of the correct data type:

```
std::string line;
while(std::getline(std::cin, line))
{
    std::stringstream ss(line);
    if ((ss >> radius) && ss.eof())
    {
       // Okay break out of loop
       break;
    }
    else
    {
       // Error!
       std::cout << "Invalid input" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This example is self explanatory, however with this approach you can't distinguish between `int` and `double` data types.

```
int main()
{
  double number = 0;

  if (!(std::cin >> number))
  {
    std::cout << "That's not a number; ";
  }
  else
  {
    std::cout << "That's  a number; ";
  }
}
```

Comment: Uhm So what if they enter, say, 0? Or is this the wont work with ints part..