# Input Validation of int C++

Tags: c++, input

I basically want to validate that I have an int and not a floating point number. What I currently have is:

```
int den1;
cout << "Enter denominator of first fraction" << endl;
cin >> den1;
while (den1 == 0){
   cout << "Enter a non-zero denominator" << endl;
   cin >> den1;
}
```

Is there a "test" to generate a boolean value for den1 == int? I'm trying to avoid using getline() because I don't want to use a string if it isn't necessary.

Comment: Check the result of the input operation.

Comment: well cin automatically converts it to an int I thought? I guess I should have included my previous two lines.

Comment: It doesn't need to. It converts to a bool, which is generally what checking the result of something operates on.

Comment: What is the type for `den1`?

Comment: @ZacHowland int. Sorry I always forget to include the little details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721911/c-how-to-verify-is-the-data-input-is-of-the-correct-datatype

Comment: @Zilog thanks for that link. I kept finding answers similar to the second answer to that question where they were using strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to force your input to be of an integer type, then use an integer type for your input.  If `den1` is an `int`, it will not let you put a floating point value in it.  That is, `cin >> den1` will be an `int` value.  If the user tries to input `3.14159`, only the 3 will be read (it will stop reading at the `.`.  Note that the rest of the buffer will contain numbers as well, so if you don't clear it, the next attempt to read an integer will read `14159`.

**EDIT**

If you want to "force" the user to enter a valid integer, you can do something like this:

std::string line;

```
int value = 0;
bool valid = false;
do
{
    if (std::getline(std::cin, line))
    {
        if (std::string::npos == line.find('.'))
        {
            // no decimal point, so not floating point number
            value = std::stol(line);
            valid = true;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
        }
    }
} while (!valid);
```

Which is a lot of extra code compared to:

```
int value;
std::cin >> value;
```

Comment: What if I want an integer to be inputted though and not a float converted to an int? I see how this would give me an integer, but I'm not sure how to loop until the user gives me an integer. Would it have something to do with having the buffer = ''?

Comment: It would not give you a "float converted to an int".  It will only read in an int.  If you want to read the whole line and convert it, you'd need to use `std::getline` with a `std::string` and then convert the numbers ... but that is unnecessary.

Comment: What I meant is, I don't want a decimal point number to become an int, I want the user to input a "valid" int, so I can loop until a user inputs 5 instead of using 5 if the user types 5.43

Comment: As I said, you can either force it by using an `int` data type, which would allow them to enter `3.14159`, but would only read the `3`, or you can read the entire line as a string, check it for a decimal point, and then convert it using `std::stol`.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use something like

```
if (std::cin >> den) {
    // process den
}
else {
    // deal with invalid input
}
```

When an input operation fails, it sets `std::ios_base::failbit` on the stream and the stream converts to `false` instead of `true`. While the stream is in this failure mode, it won't read anything from the stream, i.e., the failure mode as to be cleared, e.g., using

```
std::cin.clear();
```

Once the failure mode is cleared, the offending character still sits in the stream. You can ignore the next character using, e.g.

```
std::cin.ignore();
```

or ignore all characters until the next newline:

```
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, user input is always a string. Next, you need to define your goal more precisely. For example a reasonable thing to distinguish is whether the input can be parsed in its entirety as an integer, or as a floating point number, or neither. Here's one way to do this with iostreams, disregarding whitespace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

for (std::string line; std::getline(std::cin, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss1(line), iss2(line);
    int n;
    double x;

    if (iss1 >> n >> std::ws && iss1.get() == EOF)
    {
        // have an int, use "n"
    }
    else if (iss2 >> d >> std::ws && iss2.get() == EOF)
    {
        // have a floating point number, use "d"
    }
    else
    {
        // failed to parse the input
        continue;
    }
}
```