# C++: Obtaining the type of data entered by user via cin

Tags: c++

I would like to safeguard against the possibility that a user may enter the wrong datatype when prompted.

For example, suppose:

```
int age 
cout << "What is your age?" << endl;  
cin >> age;
```

But lets say the user types in a string or a char instead, would there be anyway for me to catch it and re-prompt the user to try again? Like:

```
if (age != dataType(int) || age !=dataType(float)
cout << "Invalid entry. Please enter a number and try again.";
```

EDIT: I understand that cin can take in characters or strings, but I need to check to see if it matches int, because in this example, a user may enter his or her age by typing it "twenty-three" for example.

Comment: Read into a `std::string` in first place, and use that one with `std::istream`, so you can check if the number extraction failed.

Comment: I think you may find this helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721911/c-how-to-verify-is-the-data-input-is-of-the-correct-datatype#12722150

Answer (score 1):

You need to do it yourself by manually parsing a string. The overloads of `operator>>` for particular types (like `int`) are there for your convenience and for the cases when you are absolutely sure that the input will be of that type. Of course you can check it for failure, but once again, for failure to read a single particular type which you expect.

In general, however, `cin` works with characters ("character input") so on the basic level you operate with character sequences (aka strings).

TL;DR: `cin` into a `string`, and then parse the string's contents yourself to determine the actual type of entered data.