# Function that validates an input as a double/integer

Tags: c++, function

So.. I am a beginner and I was creating a really "basic" calculator, I thought about what should the program do if the input was a letter instead of a number, I would use a lot of IF/else statements, clear.cin , ignore.cin, every time one of the inputs was wrong. Afterwards, I thought I would make a function to automatically check if the input was an integar, and that's what came in mind first :

```
bool checkInputDouble (char x)

{

if (x>0 || x<0 || x==0)
 {return true;}

    else
    {return false;}

}
```

I thought that these would apply to any number but not to a letter or any other character, however, it didn't work. After several trials, i found out the omitting the "x==0" condition would solve the problem, as SOMEHOW, the program thought of other characters as they equals zero. The function did its job and the calculator worked perfectly, but I thought that wasn't a practical solution, may be I will need to make a program where the user enters a number, but zero is an important input, I thought there must be like a statement or a function I don't know that would do the job, so any help ? can someone tell me what a function that REALLY does the job will look like ? and so for a function that checks for letters only, etc.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) ? What you are trying to do will always return true.

Comment: You should worry about converting from a single character — maybe you meant to pass a string or character pointer.  Assuming you want a string of some sort validated, consider `strtod()` and `strtol()` from `<cstdlib>`, both of which tell you where they stopped converting, which allows you to validate that what was entered was indeed a valid number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Check if the input is a number or string C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21807658/check-if-the-input-is-a-number-or-string-c)

Answer (score 1):

This function should work:

```
bool isDigit(char x){
   if (x>='0'&&x<='9')return true;
    else return false;}
```

You can also use the `isdigit()` function from `cctype` header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

int main(){
    std::cout<<isdigit('x')<<isdigit('0');
    return 0;}
```

Note: If you want a more generic solution which validates any type of input as double/integer, [see this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31238989/3744681).

Comment: can you explain to me this function ?
it also doesn't work with negative numbers

Comment: @Yosry How did you put a negative number in a char variable? The above function just takes a single character and checks if it is digit or not `(0-9)`

Comment: @Yosry If you want a more generic solution which takes care of negative numbers, then see this answer instead: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31238989/3744681

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17751376/2425366).

```
double GetDouble() {
    double x;
    cin >> x;
    while (cin.fail() || (cin.peek() != '\r' && cin.peek() != '\n')) {
        cout << "Invalid Input! Please input a numerical value." << endl;
        cin.clear();
        while (cin.get() != '\n');
        cin >> x;
    }
    return x;
}
```

**EDIT**: Also use functions from [numeric math](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math#Classification_and_comparison)
like `isnan()`, `isfinite()`, `isnormal()`, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You can use built in c++ isdigit funtion. In your code you are comparing character variable with integer so thats why you are getting something wrong.

You can write this like :

```
   bool checkInputDouble (char x)

    {

         if ( isdigit(x))
           return true;
         else
           return false;

    }
```

or can use your own condition like :

```
bool checkInputDouble (char x)      
        {

             if ( x >='0' && x<='9')
               return true;
             else
               return false;
        }
```