# Validate cin is positive double in C++

Tags: c++, validation, exception

I implemented a solution from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c), but it's a little buggy. This only seems to work if there are no spaces in `input`. Do I need some solution using getline instead? Thanks!

```
void numericValidation(double input)
{
        while(cin.fail())
        {
            cout << "Invalid Input. Please input a numerical value above zero." << endl;
            cin.clear();
            while(cin.get() != '\n' );
            cin >> input;
        }
}

double test;
cin >> test;
numericValidation(test); // Now I type: 1 2345 in the console (including the space)
// no error message is sent

cout << test << endl; // this prints 1
```

Comment: `floor(foo) != ceil(foo) && foo > 0` (if it really has to be a double)

Comment: The main problem I'm having is that if I actually enter "1 0.5 3 blah" in the console, input is actually set equal to 1, and this exception handling does not catch what the user typed in the console. Can I use getline instead somehow?