# Weird outputs with simple Arithmetic C++

Tags: c++

If I give this program a string as in input it gives me some very strange outputs. How do I go about handling this? I'd like it to simply state that there was an error on the consul.

```
#include <cstdlib> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() 

{ 
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Homework (out of 70 pts):  " ;
    int HW ;
    cin >> HW ;

    cout << "Midterm (out of 100 pts):  " ;
    int MT ;
    cin >> MT ;

    cout << "Final (out of 100 pts):    " ;
    int F ;
    cin >> F ;
    cout << endl;

    int S;
    S = HW + MT + F;



    cout << "Score:     " << S << endl;
    cout << endl; 

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: What exactly was weird and what error did you get on your console?

Comment: Are you saying you entered, say, "foo" to one of the numeric inputs, and got odd results?

Comment: A similar StackOverflow question with an answer is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to validate numeric input C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter a value that `cin` isn't expecting, such as a string instead of a number, nothing will be read into your variable and `cin` will set an error flag that will prevent any further input. See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3273993/how-do-i-validate-user-input-as-a-double-in-c/3274025#3274025) on the very same topic.