# Input validation for Integer and Double data types

Tags: c++, validation, input, strtod

Because there was an error in the code when I posted this question, it is not a good question. I have deleted and replaced it with a link to a correct solution.

[Correct Solution for Input Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693484/is-this-the-correct-approach-to-do-input-validation-with-floating-point-values)

Comment: As recommended you should check the length : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693484/is-this-the-correct-approach-to-do-input-validation-with-floating-point-values/7693538#7693538

of the buffer and input.

Comment: getline need buffer size. your code buffer size '\n' evaluate as integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**cin.getline(buffer, '\n');**
 <-- is wrong, need buffer size.

```
cin.getline(buffer, 10000, '\n');
```

Comment: Finally figured that out late last night before I passed out. I forgot about that parameter for c strings. with the getline member of the string class, you don't need to enter the size and I'm so used to using that. :)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest fix here is to set a limit on your 'cin.getline()' call so it doesn't overflow your buffer, or alternatively switch over to using a string class or some such like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <errno.h>

int main() {
  std::string buffer;
  double value;
  char* garbage = NULL;

  while (true) {
    std::cin >> buffer;
    std::cout << "Read in: " << buffer << std::endl;
    if (std::cin.good())
    {
      value = strtod(buffer.c_str(), &garbage);
      if (errno == ERANGE)
      {
          std::cout << "A value outside the range of representable values was returned." << std::endl;
          errno = 0;
      }
      else
      {
        std::cout << value << std::endl << garbage << std::endl;
        if (*garbage == '\0')
          std::cout << "good value" << std::endl;
        else
          std::cout << "bad value" << std::endl;
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```