# Is there special syntax to follow when comparing chars in C++?

Tags: c++, character-properties

I've been learning C++, and I tried to create a basic calculator app. The goal is to obtain two numbers from 0-9 from the user, and a mathematical operation (+, -, *, /); if some other character is typed, I want to loop the program to keep prompting for the proper input.

But whenever I run the program, it doesn't recognize the numbers 0-9, and keeps repeating the loop. These are the main 3 functions I am using. From main, I'm simply calling them, so I doubt the problem is there. Help please?

Oh and I know I'm never supposed to use go-to, but I wanted practice.
And if you could point out more efficient ways of writing this code, that's awesome.
Thanks a million.

```
int GetUserInput(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter a number between 0-9." << endl;
    
    char inputChar; 
    cin >> inputChar;

    while (inputChar != ('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || '0')) {
        cout << "Please enter a number between 0-9." << endl;
        cin >> inputChar;
    }

    return static_cast <int> (inputChar);
}

char GetMathematicalOperation(){
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Please enter a mathematical operator (+, -, *, /)" << endl;

    // Storing user input character into char inputChar
    char inputChar; 
    
    inputloop:
    cin >> inputChar;
    switch(inputChar) {
        case('+'):
        case('-'):
        case('*'):
        case('/'):
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please enter a mathematical operator (+, -, *, /)" << endl;
            goto inputloop;
        }

    return inputChar;
}

int CalculateResult(int x, char Operator, int y){
    if (Operator = '+')
        return x+y;
    if (Operator = '-')
        return x-y;
    if (Operator = '*')
        return x*y;
    if (Operator = '/')
        return x/y;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. After you fixed your first problem, please have a look at: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/stream-input-failure.html, then rewrite your input to `while(std::cin >> input)`. Also your `static_cast<int>(input)` is likely not what you want.

Comment: Please have a look here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c

Comment: Use [`std::isdigit`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isdigit).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator needs to operate on boolean expressions, which characters are not. You'd need to expand it out to `while (inputChar != '1' && inputChar != '2' && ...`.

Alternatively, you could exploit the fact that the character codes of digits are sequential. In other words, you could do `while (inputChar < '0' || inputChar > '9')`.

Also, in your `CalculateResult` function, you need to change those `=` to `==` - otherwise, you overwrite the `Operator` variable, rather than comparing to it.

Comment: Thanks Drew, this was helpful. Didn't know that I was treating the chars as bools.

Answer (score 2):

In C++

```
('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || '0') == true
```

More specifically, a `char` that has a value that is not specifically `0` (the value, not the character) evaluates to `true` when compared with the `==` or `!=` operator.

So your expression

```
inputChar != ('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || '0')
```

Is equivalent to

```
inputChar != true
```

You would do better to put all those `chars` into a container and check if the user input exists in the container.

Untested code

```
char mychars[] = {'1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0'};
std::set<char> inputChars;
inputChars.insert(mychars, mychars+10);

if(inputChars.find(inputChar) != inputChars.end())
{
...
}
```

Comment: "More specifically, a char that has a value that is not specifically 0 (the value, not the character) evaluates to true when compared with the == or != operator"
~ what does that mean? I don't understand, could you please rephrase?

Also, what is a container?

Comment: I added an example on how to use a container. As for using the `==` and `!=` operators, those operators will cast the arguments to their left and right into `bools`. If you cast a `char` into a `bool`, it will usually evaluate to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [isdigit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cctype/isdigit/) to do something like:

```
while(!isdigit(inputChar)) {  
    // code here  
}
```

Comment: Protip: adding four spaces before code will format it like code (making it much more readable).

Answer (score 1):

Another solution: `if (std::string("0123456789").find(inputChar) != std::string::npos)`. The variable `npos` - no position - means not found.

Answer (score 0):

You want to check whether the *inputChar* is outside the range '0' to '9', so you need something like this:

```
while (inputChar < '0' || inputChar > '9')
```

Comment: People should in most cases rather use `while (std::cin >> input) ...` even though your answer is correct I think it is not didactic.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I'm curious how you would do that and check that the input is in the desired range inside that one condition?

Comment: I would rather use two checks, something along the lines of `while (std::cin >> input) { if (!isValid(input)) { continue; } /* ... */ }`.  Do you disagree?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I don't think there's anything wrong with what you are suggesting, but that wasn't the problem the OP was trying to solve. When someone has a specific question, I prefer to concentrate on answering that question - not performing a full code review. I realise others may disagree with that approach, but you can always provide your own answer if you think it's important. I'm not sure it warranted downvoting my answer, but that's your choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (inputChar != ('1' || '2' || '3' || '4' || '5' || '6' || '7' || '8' || '9' || '0'))
```

You have to compare against each character.

```
while ((inputChar != '1') ||  (inputChar != '2') ....
```

Or simply -

```
while ((inputChar < 47) || (inputChar > 57))
```

Next,

```
if (Operator = '+')
```

Compiler should have given you warning. Its an assignment. You actually need `==` operator instead if you intend to do comparison.

Comment: Did you mean `while (inputChar > '9')`? Also, what if the user enters a space? That's less than `'9'`.

Comment: With out `''` them, it should work as there is an conversion between `char` to `int`. Also, ASCII value of space character is 32. [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f0fbc54811062a295e488be2a7125080-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51).

Comment: Oh I can't believe I missed that, thanks a lot. Yeah I don't know why my compiler didn't throw an error, it has in the past for incorrect assignments. I'm using Visual Studio 2012, are there any known bugs with that?

And why can't I compare my inputChar against '1' || '2' .... ? 
And how does inputChar > 9 work? Wouldn't inputChar have to be an int type to make such a comparison?

Comment: Converting character '9' to `int` is value 57 (that's the ASCII code of '9').

Comment: Mahesh what do you mean? I checked out the link, what conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition is wrong...you need to check (inputchar != '0') && (inputchar != '1') && ... && (inputchar != '9')