# cin fails to stop while loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I was wondering if you guys could explain to me why this loop doesn't loop if I enter 'r' in for the value of 'value'.

```
double value

std::cout << "Please enter a real number: ";
std::cin  >> value;

while (!isdigit(value))
{
    std::cout << "Sorry, but only numbers are valid.\nPlease enter a real number: ";
    std::cin  >> value;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: How did you declare `value`?

Comment: Edited for value declaration

Comment: What does "isdigit" do?

Comment: isdigit checks if the passing value is a number and nothing else. Search for it on cplusplus

Comment: If you enter a non-digit character for `value`, it is considered a failed input operation. The character is *not* extracted into `value`.

Comment: `isdigit` seems to work for strings, not numbers

Comment: _'value is a number'_ you missed reading further _value is a number **character**_

Comment: Oops, I just saw your edit that value is a double.  See this for how to do what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c

isdigit is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be using `isdigit()` here because that's for testing whether a single `char` type is an ASCII digit.

If you're expecting the user to enter a real number (and not a string), then you should use `cin.fail()` as your loop test condition. If `cin` reads a string when it's expecting a `double` then `cin.fail()` will return `true`.

Another (cleaner) option is to just test the state of `cin` as **@bennofs** pointed out:

```
while (!(std::cin >> value))
{
    // bad value was entered
}
```

Comment: or just use the result of `std::cin >> value`

Answer (score 1):

You did two things wrong: You declared `value` as a `double`, and you used `std::cin >> value` to populate that incorrectly declared variable.

You need to read a character, so read a character. Declare `value` as a `char`.

**Edit**: I am assuming your assignment is to read a character and see if it represents one of the numeric digits. If your assignment is to read a number, you are going about this all wrong.