# Integer or double 1.0 and 1

Tags: c++

I want to read a double number and determine if the input is Integer or double. The problem is that when I enter `1.00` (which is double) I get the result as integer

```
double a;
cin >> a;
if (a == int(a))
    cout << "Integer";
else
    cout << "Double";
```

Comment: Read as a string, and then see if the string contains a decimal separator (could be `','` as well, depending on locale settings). For conversion and further validation use e.g. [`std::stod`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof).

Comment: The result is not an integer, your check is simply wrong. you declare `a` to be a double, so `cin >> a;` will assign whatever you type to a double, so `a` will never be an Integer. If you want to check whether the input is formatted like an integer or a floating point type (float, double, long double) and contains e.g. a `.` like `1.0` or `.5`, assign the input to a string and check how the value is formatted.

Comment: I already know this method, but what I am asked to do is to read from a double not a string.

Comment: If you read as a double then you really can't tell if the user entered 1.0 or 1. The double doesn't store or retain a difference.

Comment: #Elijan9 I have made several tests and all of them show me that 1.0 is integer rather than double

Comment: drescherjm even when I read from integer (int a) and try 1.0 I still get the result as integer

Comment: A variable of type *double* is never an integer.  Presumably that's what a call a double whose fraction is 0.  Use this: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps `std::variant` is an elegant way to solve your problem. `std::variant<int, double>` can store both an `int` or a `double`. Dependent on what you store the internal type will change.

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <cassert>


bool isInt(const std::variant<int, double> &intOrDouble) {
    try {
      std::get<double>(intOrDouble); 
    }
    catch (const std::bad_variant_access&) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    std::variant<int, double> intOrDouble;
    intOrDouble = 12.0; // type will be double -> return will be 1
    //intOrDouble = 12; // type will be int    -> return will be 0

    return isInt(intOrDouble); 
}
```

Comment: That's neat but how would you read from standard input without knowing the type you are reading? If the value is already read, what's stopping you from comparing `typeid`s?

Comment: Exactly, though I did not know it would be that terribly difficult

Comment: `c++` is statically typed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517582/what-is-the-difference-between-statically-typed-and-dynamically-typed-languages

Comment: @drescherjm How is this relevant?

Comment: I got the feeling Florian wanted `c++` to behave like a dynamically typed language.

Answer (score 3):

You can read into a string and check if it contains the decimal separator. Assuming it is '.', here's an example implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  std::cout << ((s.find('.') == std::string::npos) ? "integer" : "double") << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

You also have to check for exponents (like `2e-1`). Here's one way to do it all:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
  std::string s;
  std::cin >> s;
  if (s.find_first_of(".,eE") == std::string::npos)
    std::cout << "integer" << std::endl;
  else
    std::cout << "double" << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: My task is to read from a double and thats why I am stuck for several hours

Comment: @Florian You're stuck because your task is impossible. You cannot read a double and then know what text was used to produce that double. That information was lost when the conversion to a double was performed. The **only** way to do this, as the answer above states, its to read the input as **text**, and analyse the text. Then convert the text to a double if that's what you wish to do.

Comment: You would also need to check if the input contains an exponent. For instance 123e-2 is a double, but doesn't contain a decimal separator.

Comment: No problem hoenstly the task is very simple just could not understand why 1.00 is not double because when we want to convert int to double we can simplly say (2 + 2 = 4 integer) (2 + 2.00 = 4 double)

Comment: @john thanks for pointing out. Tried to add that in but I used `strpbrk` because I couldn't find a direct C++ replacement. Is there any?

Comment: @Florian 1.00 *is* a double. What makes you think it isn't one?

Comment: Ayxan sure it is double but when I put( int a ) in my code instaed of (double a) and intered (1.00 ) I was still getting same resut 1.00 / 1 integer and this is the reason why I have asked

Comment: @john and ayxan thank you so much for your great effort

Comment: @Florian it's a bit like `int a = 1.00;` and `double d = 1;` compiler casts those to fit into the variable you created. And whenever you try to compare an `int` and a `double`, the integer is cast to a double first, and then they are compared. Meaning `1 == 1.00` and `1.00 == 1.00` are precisely the same thing

Comment: Ok, I have got it

Answer (score 2):

In your if statement you are casting a to an int.  This is just going to truncate the decimal value.

1==1 is always true as is 1.0 == 1

I would suggest looking at this answer:
[How to validate numeric input C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514420/how-to-validate-numeric-input-c)

Comment: The answer your looking for is from Raúl Roa

Comment: You could share a link directly to the answer by clicking "share" under it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/514495/10147399